# Wait only for 5 seconds for a button to be clicked else other player wins the game

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am creating a tic tac toe game where i have a condition, that if player does not respond within 5 seconds he loses the game. player responds by clicking a button. Do we have something like this to do?

i tried implementing this by having a list  of times when the button was clicked and check whether a new button click happened in the next 5 seconds or not. it works well on the first click but complexities arise when multiple clicks are added.

[image: code of what i tried]

Comment: FYI, the reason that your question has received some downvotes is probably because you haven't explained what you have already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class that records the last time a button was clicked, with a method that returns whether the next click was within 5 seconds.

```
class ClickCheck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_click = None

    def clicked_in_time(self) -> bool:
        # Handle the first click.
        if self.last_click is None:
            self.last_click = time.time()
            return True
        
        # Handle later clicks.
        new_click = time.time()
        if new_click - self.last_click > 5:
            return False
        self.last_click = new_click
        return True
```

You will need to create an instance of `ClickCheck`, and create a callback function that is called when your button is clicked. Inside that callback, call the `clicked_in_time` method of your `ClickCheck` instance and it will tell you whether it was clicked in time. The rest of the code in your callback function can then decide how to handle ending or continuing the game.

Comment: thankyou. can you also help me with  how to add the callback function when button is clicked. i am new to python. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Learnt about callbacks and was able to implement it. Thank you, helped me a lot.

Comment: Your welcome! Glad you got it working :)